# I Just Wonder Why I Can't Login to a Site Collection Using a Domain Account

Tags: site-collection, login

I use a domain account to login to a site collection, but I get failure. I have tried to fix this by disabling loopback. When I create a new site collection under a new web app it works. Even so,  I still can't login to the original site collection.

Comment: Do you get access denied or a rejected login?

Comment: Rejected login.

Comment: Are both web apps using the same User Profile Service? If not, ensure that the User Profile information is present in the UPS of the web app in question.

Comment: I have fix the issue,I took the IIS Authentication Settings as Negotiate in Authentication Provider for the first Web App.  Do you have any idea about access denied? It appears in another Farm.

Comment: Check the security settings of the user on the affected site/list/library. If you go to Manage Permissions, there is an option in the ribbon for Check Permissions. Type in the user name and you will see what their permissions are for that site/list/library.